# Browsers tabs keeps on getting open, How to stop that?, In Javascript Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openurl

Guys Actually i want to open a new browser tab from the back-end, i am using ***https://www.npmjs.com/package/opener*** npm library to do that,

If i use URL ***https://www.google.com*** or any other common URL it is working fine 
But if i use ***http://localhost:3000/*** in broweser, tabs are keeps on getting open.

```
router.post('/paths',async (req, res)=>{
          var openBrowsers = require('open-browsers');
          openBrowsers('http://localhost:3000/')
}
```

I have tried with using below npm libraries as well but same output i am getting that it keeps on getting open new Tabs

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/openurl
https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-url
https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn
https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-url-js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/open
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing localhost:3000 is the URL of the server that's running the script to open the tabs. To test this simply make another simple server, on another port, and try opening that. Later, if you want to use the same server, then, on the server side, only open the new tabs if some specific header is sent, or something else (best to post your full code)

Comment: Yes, Actually i am opening the localhost:3000 from another server called localhost:5000,
from localhost:5000 i am triggering '/path' function which is there in localhost:3000.